# android maps v2 custom overlay disappears on zoom

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

At zoom levels not included in my map cache, generated by MapTiler, Android Maps v2 does not display the map.  My understanding was that Android Maps v2 will use the highest zoom level available for a given tile cache, so why is it hiding the layer?

On closer inspection, it's because the tile provider I've implemented returns null, indicating no tile available.  Android Maps v2 doesn't seem to hold onto the lower resolution copy and display it, instead  just opting to show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. If you don't like it, you may post a feature request on gmaps-api-issues. I have a feeling it won't be implemented, because the tiles would look ugly.

Comment: right so the real answer is to bump up the resolution of the tile source before generating the cache.  makes sense I guess, but there are use cases where you might want to use an offline tile cache for when network isn't available, and can't have it at the highest resolution because of huge size of a his res cache.  In this cause it's unfortunate to have the low res tiles disappear, with nothing behind them.

Comment: @deepwinter You may always take part of a cached tile and make new tiles out of it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here.  Making new tiles out of a cached tile has the effect of creating the hugely sized cache level, as zoom level 19 say is very large indeed for raster graphics.  It's much more desirable just to lock the map to a maximum zoom in these kinds of cases.