# Android maps V2 tiles disappear when zooming

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps V2 for Android and have a tile overlay that gets it's tiles from a server online. This all works great and the tiles are displayed correctly at all zoom levels. The issue I am having is when I zoom in/out the current tile is instantly removed from view and the tiles are gone until the next tile has been downloaded. What I would like to happen is the tile will remain and just become pixelated until the new tile is ready. It seems like this is exactly how Google's tile work, if I zoom the roads and such become pixelated and then once the new tile is download they look sharp. Is there a way to do this using maps V2?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the same problem [android maps v2 custom overlay disappears on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712898/android-maps-v2-custom-overlay-disappears-on-zoom)

Probably there isn't fix for this.