# Android google maps tile overlay update on zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a tile overlay in Android Google Map. Everything works fine. But when I zoom in, all tiles disappear then new tiles are downloaded and only after 1-2 secs(when new tiles are downloaded) the map shows them. Therefore, the map doesn't show tiles for some time. Is there a way to update tiles only when new tiles are downloaded?

I use a basic UrlTileProvider and Aeris Overlay maps.

[image]

Comment: did u figure it out i am having the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you can [download each tile as image](https://www.google.com/search?ei=7XMFXL7FHpKIrwSK6rb4AQ&q=android+download+png+from+url+&oq=android+download+png+from+url+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.485318.485318..486192...0.0..0.96.96.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.AOFRsCdezio) to local internal or external storage with, for example, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library (or separate `Thread` or `AsyncTask`) and determine "all new tiles are downloaded" event "manually" (e.g. increment downloaded tiles counter on every `public void onSuccess()` for Picasso or `protected void onPostExecute()` for `AsyncTask` or on end of `public void run()` for `Thread` and wait that equals all tiles quantity) then use [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) for downloaded tiles local storage like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov).

**Update**

For showing previous map when tiles for zoom+1 level still downloading it's possible to create [`GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) with screenshot of current map view. Screenshot of google map you can do like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773658/6950238) question of [DiscDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103584/discdev)

**Update #2**

There are several ways to solve you problem: 1) you can create custom view which extends `MapView` class like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238) answer and show in overriden`dispatchDraw()` method whatever you want or 2) you can set `ImageView` over your `MapView` and show it with screenshot on it while zoom changed and new tiles loaded. And if necessary you can translate tap events from `ImageView` to `MapView` and so on.

I prefer p.1 - create `MapView`-based custom view, override `dispatchDraw()` and show temporary map within it while new map loading.

Comment: I already download the tiles locally and the problem still exist, basically what happen is whenever i zoom to the next level google map suddenly remove the current tiles from screen and show empty screen. After that it takes around a second to load the next tiles locally and show them. which is annoying as a user experience

Comment: Try to create GroundOverlay with downloaded tiles.

Comment: my tiles are loaded from local storage ,i already downloaded them

Comment: if u try to zoom in google map app => the app keeps zooming through the current tile image  until the next zoom tiles are loaded

Comment: i am afraid there is no solution for my problem:( ((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200990/android-maps-v2-tiles-disappear-when-zooming